# EF Plus IncludeFilter does not reset

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code for my EF Repository, using `Entity Framework Plus`:

```
    public IEnumerable<League> GetLeaguesWithTeamsByYear(int year)
    {
        return Context.Leagues.IncludeFilter(l => l.Teams.Where(t => t.Year == year));
    }
```

This works great, as when I select the year (say, 1871), I get all the teams for a league for 1871.

However, when I then switch to 1872, I get all teams for 1871 and then 1872. It seems that the filter stays on my current Context. Is there a way to disable that filter so that I'm only including teams from a certain year?

Comment: are you using the same `DbContext` or a new instance with the second call?  If the same context is used, the 1871 teams will still be tracked in the `DbContext` and will appear in the `League` entities'  `Teams` collections.

Comment: Same `DbContext` Should I be creating a new one with each call to my repository though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that you're using the same `DbContext` instance so tracked entities from prior calls are included in later calls' `League.Teams` collection results.  You could try `.AsNoTracking()` to see if that helps but it might prevent hooking up the results of EF Plus's filtered include to the `League.Teams` collection (it does just that w/ regular EF implementation).

Personally, I would project and then compose the results I want w/o EF Plus.  For example:

```
return Context.Leagues.Select( l => new
{
    League = l,
    Teams = l.Teams.Where( t => t.Year == year ),
}
.ToArray()
.Select( at =>
{
    var l = at.League;
    l.Teams = at.Teams;
    return l;
} );
```

I don't like reusing the `League` class here as another user may think the entire `Teams` collection is loaded somewhere down the code road.  Perhaps create a DTO for such usage.

Another solution is to start with the other end and group by league:

```
return Context.Teams.Where( t => t.Year == year )
    .GroupBy( t => t.League );
```

`TKey` is `League` and and `TElement` is `Team` (below is for illustrative purposes, the `IGrouping<League, Team>` result should be sufficient for your usage):

```
results.Select( g => new
{
    League = g.Key,
    Teams = g,
} );
```

All that said, if you're not interested in tracking the entities, using a different `DbContext` instance per call shouldn't significantly hurt performance.

Comment: Are DTO's a good way to go? I've been hesitant to use them as I fear they're redundant, no?

Comment: I'm probably just going to use a new `DbContext` each time. This call would only be for analysis purposes anyway. Thanks!